# ViewControllers data sending confusion

Tags: ios, parameter-passing, segue

I've got interesting problem. I have 3 view controllers (lets name them tableViewControler A, viewControler B, final tableViewController C). They all concern filtering data.

In A I select one of the main categories, in next step, I send name of selected category to B (in didSelectRowAtIndexPath like this

```
FilterTableViewController *fViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"filterTableView"]; //B view controller
fViewController.passedValue = [categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

)
Controller B's purpose is additional filtering of data (like if there is any timeleft, which item has highest price etc). B has mentioned passedValue (string with category name). After user selects filters, and click on button, C is getting pushed.

Now, in C, I have public NSString "selectedCat". This string should have data assigned in B before performing segue to C

```
FilterResultViewController *resViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"resController"]; //C viewController
resViewController.selectedCat = passedValue;
```

Now, in C, I'm making request for data. It's http request and Im getting JSON back. This all works fine. My problem however is, that selectedCat is (NULL). I made NSLogs to see, where do my data get lost. What I found out is even more confusing.

Here is my console log

```
2012-11-30 12:27:07.976 portal_postupne[4510:11303] selected sports //This NSLog is in A
2012-11-30 12:27:10.542 portal_postupne[4510:11303] category = (null)// This NSLog is in C
2012-11-30 12:27:10.653 portal_postupne[4510:11303] passed category: sports//This NSLog is in B and gets called on button click that pushes C
```

So basically my C view Controller gets somehow called before B. I guess that's why my category is empty. I also tried to instantiate C in A and set category value in A. Null again.

Next thing, I was doing my table view in viewWillAppear method. However I moved it to viewDidLoad later, but this didn't fix my problem.

Please help :)

Comment: Put a breakpoint in C's `viewDidLoad` and look at the stack trace to see what's causing it to be called early.

Comment: I'm beginner and I have problem reading stack traces :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "solved" it by this, probably wrong approach.
I saved  category value in NSUserDefaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[categories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forKey:@"kategoria"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

And then call it in C when I set parameters for HTTP request.

```
NSMutableString *parameters = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    [ms appendFormat:@"&category=%@",[defaults objectForKey:@"kategoria"]];
```

However I don't think, this is the "correct" approach.

Comment: Since there were no responds I accepted this. Please if you can give me any better solution, feel free to reply.